# Blurry text in low resolution game using TMP

Tags: unity, gui, text, text-mesh-pro

This could be a simple solution that my mind cant grab right now. So, I am working on a game with a specific resolution which is 64x64. I using unity latest version. as for my text I am using TMP. My set up right now is have a root canvas with multiple children's canvasses in it. this is currently my step for the root canvas and children canvasses will inherit those settings. [image]

For my TMP set up I am pretty much using the normal font TMP came with. I tried to make the scale of the text to be small and the font size to be large, but that was no luck. This is currently the set up for it.

[image]

Result I am getting: [image]

Comment: For such a low-resolution game, you'd likely want to use a pixel font designed for low resolution display, not a generic font designed for desktop resolutions.

Comment: @DMGregory I tried using a pixel-style fonts from dafont.com, but no luck with multiple ones.  Might have to look deeper

Comment: Searching "pixel font in Unity" turns up [guides like this one](https://pavcreations.com/pixel-perfect-fonts-in-unity-the-practical-guide/) — have you tried following these steps or similar tutorials?

Comment: @DMGregory I thought about that. Creating the font from scratch. Since I have not done it before and how to do it. I saw a couple of tutorials about it. I guess I might do it.  I thought there might be other solution to it other than that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Another (quick and dirty) solution could be to draw the Play text with pixels as an image. Good solution for a jam if you've only got a couple of buttons. Good luck!

Comment: I suspect it may not be TMP  specific. I have the same problem with pixel perfect camera set at 480x270. It looks sharp when rendered at x4 (1920x1080) screen res. But when the screen res is set to exactly match camera res everything becomes blurry. Sadly still haven't found a way to make camera and screen res to play along well together.